# Putting body into a DIV kills the event

Tags: javascript, jquery

dont ask me why, but I want to put the whole body into a div, and shrink the content. I have this so far:

```
$('#newButton').click(function() {
    if ($('#xxxx').length == 0)
    {
        $('body').html('<div id="xxxx">'+$('body').html()+'</div>');
        $('#xxxx').css('background-color', 'red').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    }
    alert ($('#xxxx').width());
    $('#xxxx').width (parseInt($('#xxxx').width())-10+'px');
});
```

this is ok so far - but then this click() method never triggers again. For an unknown reason, its killed....

Comment: I have to ASK YOU WHY !

Comment: Im gonna tell it, when I get the answer :)

Comment: It's never triggered again because you've destroyed the original element. Use event delegation: `$('document').on('click','#newButton',function() {`

Comment: well, uh, its OK for one element, but it cant be done for ALL available elements.... and did I destroy? Didnt I just put it into a container?

Comment: Nope, you destroyed the original DOM element when you updated the `.html()`. Then you created a new element with the same ID, but no event handler. Perhaps you should use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) instead.

Comment: ok, but.... that "$('body').append('<div id="xxxx">'+$('body').html()+'</div>');" duplicates the content.

Comment: If you're just trying to wrap all of `body`'s content in a div this just use `$('body > *').wrapAll( "<div id="xxxx" />");` [Warpall](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You destroyed the original DOM element when you updated the `.html()`. Then you created a new element with the same ID, but no event handler. (Remember, HTML isn't the same as the DOM elements. When you remove and replace the HTML, whole new DOM elements are created from that code.)

You could solve this with [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$('document').on('click','#newButton',function() {
```

But I would use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) instead:

```
if ($('#xxxx').length == 0) {
    $('body > *').wrapAll('<div id="xxxx">');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<style>
    #xxxx{ position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; background: none; display: none; }
</style>

$('#newButton').click(function() {
    if ($('#xxxx').length == 0)
    {
        $('body').append('<div id="xxxx">'+$('body').html()+'</div>');
        $('#xxxx').css('background-color', 'red')
          .css('overflow', 'scroll')
          .css("display", "block";
    }
    alert ($('#xxxx').width());
    $('#xxxx').width (parseInt($('#xxxx').width())-10+'px');
});
```

this will copy a new "body" (actually it's a div with the same content) on top of the old body.

Answer (score 0):

for those why I want it (it might be weird, but we programmers has to get used to weird solutions).
I wanted to simplify to check the site with shrank windows, so with - and + you can decrease/increase the "window":

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var doResizing = function (increaseWith)
{
    if ($('#xxxx').length == 0)
    {
        $('body').css('margin', 0).css('padding', 0);
        $('body > *').wrapAll('<div id="xxxx" /></div>');
        $('#xxxx').css('background-color', 'red').css('overflow', 'scroll').css('padding', 0).css('margin', 0).css('position', 'absolute').width('100%');
    }
    $('#xxxx').height(parseInt($(window).height())+'px').width(parseInt($('#xxxx').width())+increaseWith+'px');
}

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 45) { doResizing (-10); }
    if (e.which == 43) { doResizing (+10); }
});

});
```

enjoy!